# Any potential bug or issue in this ConvertOrigin?

Tags: xcm, cross-chain

I want to use the following ConvertOrigin. It converts a sibling account into the native account.

```
pub struct SiblingSignedAccountId32AsNative<Origin>(PhantomData<Origin>);
impl<Origin: OriginTrait> ConvertOrigin<Origin>
    for SiblingSignedAccountId32AsNative<Origin>
where
    Origin::AccountId: From<[u8; 32]>,
{
    fn convert_origin(
        origin: impl Into<MultiLocation>,
        kind: OriginKind,
    ) -> Result<Origin, MultiLocation> {
        let origin = origin.into();
        log::trace!(
            target: "xcm::origin_conversion",
            "SiblingSignedAccountId32AsNative origin: {:?}, kind: {:?}",
            origin, kind,
        );
        match (kind, origin) {
            (
                OriginKind::Native,
                MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Junctions::X2(Parachain(_), AccountId32 { id, _ })},
            ) =>
                Ok(Origin::signed(id.into())),
            (_, origin) => Err(origin),
        }
    }
}
```

I think it's safe and won't bring any asset security issue. However I don't find similar ConvertOrigin in polkadot's repo.

Is there any reason behind or this ConvertOrigin could cause some issues?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.